# Configuring yasnippet and autocomplete to work with C/C++ headers

Tags: auto-complete-mode, yasnippet, linux, c++

My computer system and set up are

```
OS: Arch Linux 64bit
emacs version: 24.4
alias emacs='emacsclient -t -s server --alternate-editor='
```

---

**Update:**

`auto complete` is working with `yasnippet` occasionally now but not as expected. I changed the line

```
(add-to-list 'achead:include-directories
       '"/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/")
```

If I type `#include <io` and hit tab, I get back `#include <#include <iostream>`. Therefore, I then tried just typing `<io` and tab which produces `<#include <iostream>`. If I type `ios` and hit type, the desired result is achieved. I then tested this with `float.h`. No iteration works.

I then tried re-testing `io` and tab. This doesn't work 100% of the time. 50% of the time I get `#include <iostream>` and the other 50% nothing happens. Needless to say, I have no idea what is going on with this package or feature.

---

I am trying to get auto complete to work with C/C++ headers; however, I have been unable to do so. I executed the following command in the terminal to locate the C/C++ headers:

```
[dustin@dustin ~]$ g++ -print-prog-name=cc1plus -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/cc1plus
```

but using `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/cc1plus` does not produce the desired outcome. I have also ran a search looking for `float.h` just to determine locations as well and came up with

```
[dustin@dustin ~]$ sudo find / -name float.h
[sudo] password for dustin: 
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/tr1/float.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/float.h
```

So I also tried `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include`. I am not to sure about `/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/tr1` though.

Below is the relevant information in my `.emacs`. All packages were downloaded and install from `melpa` are up-to-date. If I run `'emacs' --debug-init`, there are no error messages. The `' '` around emacs is so that emacs will open without options for debugging only.

```
;; Start server and set directory
(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000"))

;; Package list M-x package-list-packages
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

;; Package initialize
(package-initialize)

;; C/C++ configuration
(require 'cc-mode)

;; auto complete for C/C++
(require 'auto-complete)
;; default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;; start yasnippets
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; auto complete C++-headers
(defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-header)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories
               '"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include")
  )

;; call ac-c-headers from c/c++ hooks
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
```

Comment: Seems like you are new to Emacs. If so, my [C/C++ guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) may help you get a good development environment with IDE like features like navigate around large project with 30k files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on SO the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231619/emacs-auto-complete-c-headers-symbols-value-as-variable-is-void/27546823#27546823) that works by [abdimuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255631/abdimuna):

First locate C/C++ headers on your computer by running the following command.

```
gcc -xc++ -E -v -
```

On my ArchLinux they are located here

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
```

Then the complete C/C++ auto-completion which works for me is this.

```
;; C++ auto completion mode
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
;a function which initializes auto-complete-c-headers and get called for c/c++ hooks
(defun my:acc-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '" /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../include/c++/4.9.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include"
     )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hippie-expand` and avoid all this key binding conflict headache altogether:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand) ;; replace dabbrev-expand
  (setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
        '(
          ;; Try to expand yasnippet
          yas-hippie-try-expand
          ;; Try to expand word "dynamically", searching the current buffer.
          try-expand-dabbrev
          ;; Try to expand word "dynamically", searching all other buffers.
          try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers
          ;; Try to expand word "dynamically", searching the kill ring.
          try-expand-dabbrev-from-kill
          ;; Try to complete text as a file name, as many characters as unique.
          try-complete-file-name-partially
          ;; Try to complete text as a file name.
          try-complete-file-name
          ;; Try to expand word before point according to all abbrev tables.
          try-expand-all-abbrevs
          ;; Try to complete the current line to an entire line in the buffer.
          try-expand-list
          ;; Try to complete the current line to an entire line in the buffer.
          try-expand-line
          ;; Try to complete as an Emacs Lisp symbol, as many characters as
          ;; unique.
          try-complete-lisp-symbol-partially
          ;; Try to complete word as an Emacs Lisp symbol.
          try-complete-lisp-symbol))
```

Now, whenever you want to expand a snippet, press <kbd>M-/</kbd> and want to complete, press <kbd><tab></kbd>.

Comment: It only expands to float not float.h. Is that intended?

Comment: @dustin I added the function for expanding yasnippet snippets `yas-hippie-try-expand`.  Sorry about that. It should expand snippets properly now. As for completing headers, I'm not sure about it. I only use [company-c-header](https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers). As for `hippie-expand`, it only expands from the candidates generated by functions in the list, so it won't complete your header files.