# Indentation in makefile: alignment in multi-line assignments

Tags: makefile-mode, indentation

What is the best solution for writing Makefile, GNU Makefile specifically?

For example:

```
FILES:= file0.cpp          \
        file1.cpp          \
        file2.cpp          \
        fileYetAnother.cpp
```

After typing the first `\`(or after saving the buffer), and `ENTER`, I want the file1.cpp to align with the file0.cpp, do not mind the `\` at the end of each line, I can use `align-regexp` to align all of them after finished.

But it turns out this by default:

```
FILES:= file0.cpp  \
file1.cpp          \
file2.cpp          \
fileYetAnother.cpp
```

I know I can define my own indentation like [Customizing indentation in makefile mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3644/794), but it will fix the indentation to number like 4, that is not smart for different situations, what if the `FILES` word is long.

Besides it does not work for:

```
all:
        gcc ...
```

I have to type `C-q TAB` to indent the `gcc ...` line.

Another problem for this kind of situation, by default, if you keep typing `TAB` below the `all:` line and then type the real commands for `all`, Emacs will keep inserting `Tab` when typing `TAB`, AFAIK, it must be 8 spaces (a `Tab` exactly） at the beginning of the command line after `all`, so typing multiple typing-`TAB`s should only remain one `TAB`.

Is there any package to handle all the messed up format in the Makefile, or you just do that manually?

Comment: I don't have an automatic solution, but the multiple-cursors library allows one to edit multiple lines simultaneously, so you can manually adjust several lines extremely quickly with just a couple of keystrokes.  You could set up tab-stops, or a certain number of spaces to quickly indent multiple lines and likewise jump to the ends of all lines and move the back-slashes over a bit -- the same holds true for jumping to the beginning of multiple lines.  I recently set up colors for multiple cursors so I can see whether I'm on an odd-col or an even-col and you could do that for tab-stops, etc.

Comment: @lawlist yeah, I can do that using mc or other methods manually, but are all Emacs users manually doing this manually when writing Makefile or these problems cannot be automatically? I highly doubt that.

Comment: Why don't you abandon `Makefile`:s and use something more modern like http://www.cmake.org/

Comment: @Lindydancer It's my company's project, they don't use cmake

Comment: There might not be very many people actually writing complicated Makefiles... Most people try to avoid it, so I'd say no wonder the editing is uncomfortable. I wouldn't say that Automake is better... but from what I see, people prefer to generate Makefiles. To me, the only reason to ever use Make is its ubiquity, but if that's a company's internal project, I'd never hesitate to use something that is much easier to work with, SCons would be a good example.

Comment: @wvxvw SCons is nice, not the solution for this post though.

Comment: @CodyChan For a wordaround, it's easier to write Makefile by binding `TAB` to just insert a tab character in `makefile-mode`. That's what I am doing.

Comment: @CodyChan to make tab appear 8 spaces, simply set `tab-width` in `makefile-mode` via a hook.

Comment: In my Emacs, TAB is bound to insert a tab character in `makefile-gmake-mode`.  I did not need to set up anything.

Comment: @TuDo About the "`TAB` to just insert a tab character in `makefile-mode`", what if TAB is already bound to `yas-expand` globally in the package, rebind `yas-expand` to another key?

Comment: @CodyChan you can simply use `M-/` and configure `hippie-expand` to expand snippets. See [my answer here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10704/200). As for Makefile, I don't recall it has any snippet or has sophisticated completion that `company` is needed. If you want to use `company` for word completion, simply configure `company` that it automatically shows popup every 0.02 second idle.

Comment: @TuDo I already bound `M-/` to `hippie-expand` and `yas-hippie-try-expand` is in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`, but I didn't notice that I can use `M-/` to expand snippets, I always used `TAB` for snippets, thanks.